# How to echo PHP HashMaps

Tags: php, riot-games-api

I'm new in PHP developing and need your help.
I write a web page [summoner-info.com](http://summoner-info.com/) with the RIOT API.
but I'm too bad to understand the documentation.
I want to output via echo my states. In the API docs stands:

Return Value: `Map[string, List[LeagueDto]]`

But I don't understand how to use this.

Doc link: [link](https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/985/3356)

I wrote this:

```
$url = "https://{$region}.api.pvp.net/api/lol/{$region}/v2.5/league/by-summoner/{$summoner_ID}?api_key={$api}";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($data);
```

So how can I write something like this

```
echo $data["tier"["LeagueDto "]]
```

Comment: A multidimensional array is accessed using separate indexes as in `$data["tier"]["LeagueDto"]`.

Comment: but it dindt work... i dont know if i miss understand the doc....

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($data)`? If you let us know that the data looks like, we can tell you how to access it.

Comment: No. I cannot. The website is blocked by our network. Post some of it in the question so we can see it.

Comment: @JustDanny Edit/Delete your link, you posted your API key there. Also, what exactly are you trying to access in plain text? Which information? Have you found anything useful here yet? https://developer.riotgames.com/discussion/tutorials-libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the kind of response you're expecting (2 summoner ids):

https://github.com/josephyi/taric/blob/master/spec/fixtures/leagues_by_summoner_ids.json

There's no LeagueDto entry in the JSON response. When Riot refers to 'LeagueDto' that's the class that represents the data of the object, but is not meant to be accessed from the response. If you look at the response, you'll have to navigate the JSON. I don't know PHP, but assuming you want summoner id 21066:

```
$data["21066"] // array of leagues the summoner is in
$data["21066"][0] // first league the summoner is in
$data["21066"][0]["entries"] // array of league entries for the first league
$data["21066"][0]["tier"] // tier of first league
```

Hope that helps!